# existdb util:get-fragment-between to get fragment from node to end of file

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In some prior iteration of the exist-db version, the following code was working to create a fragment between a specific starting node and the end of the file (aka, everything that follows until the end).

Here's the code:

```
let $beginning-node := $doc/tei:TEI//tei:body//tei:pb[@ed=$initial_with_hash][@n=$surface_number_start]

let $ending-node := $doc/tei:TEI//tei:body//tei:pb[@ed=$initial_with_hash[@n=$surface_number_start]//following

let $make-fragment := true()
let $display-root-namespace := true()
let $fragment := util:get-fragment-between($beginning-node, $ending-node, $make-fragment, $display-root-namespace)
```

Today I realized that this code, though unchanged, is no longer working. Specifically, there seems to be problem with using the `//following` to create the `$ending-node`. So I suspect a change has been made in an updated version and I need to update my code somehow. The question is how.

In this particularly case, there is a specific element I want the fragment to begin from and then I want the fragment to include everything that follows, but in such I case I'm not sure how to properly provide and `$ending-node`

If anyone has ideas about I could update this so that it will start working again, I would be grateful.

Comment: Someone reported an issue with this function changing behavior. Does this match what you're experiencing? https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/4140

Comment: HI @JoeWicentowski. I saw this and it looked very similar. I tried my existing code on both 5.3 and 6 and it doesn't work as it used to. I think it was working when I was running version 3

Comment: If you think your problem might be distinct, I'd advise creating a reproducible test showing your expected vs. actual results (ideally, one like the XQSuite in the linked issue) and posting this in a new issue.